# Context Root is not working in Internet Explorer 11 version

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ember.js, internet-explorer-11

My local host (http://localhost:8080/) is working fine with Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) version. But context root (http://localhost:8080/context-root) is not working??

While opening the product through IE11 the http://localhost:8080/context-root, its not showing any page, it's simply showing blank page. In that there is showing below two errors

SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'

File: context.js, Line: 1980, Column: 50

```
{
                        iframe = $('<iframe src="' + jsFalse + '" name="' + name + '" style="display:none"></iframe>');
                        iframe.addClass('iframe-transport');
                        form.attr('accept-charset', 'utf-8');
                        $("body").append(iframe);
                        iframe.append(form);
                        iframe.bind("load", {form,collider} ,winLoader);
                    }
```

This line(iframe.bind("load", {form,collider} ,winLoader);) was mentioned in the error and another error is

SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined

File: default.js, Line: 1, Column: 1

```
$(function () {
    context.start(context.view.Application);
});
```

But the same localhost cite is working fine with chrome and Mozilla. Can anyone help me on this. I'm new with the ember. Thanks in advance

Comment: this `{form,collider}` is not correct syntax. If it should be an object as key/value pair it'd be `{form: collider}` . Or should it be an array maybe? Then `[form,collider]`

Comment: But the second argument of bind should be a function, right?

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Now that error gone. Now I'm getting this syntax error. var value = this.get('pairs').map((pair) => (pair.name || '') + '=' + (pair.value || ''));

Comment: missing the `{ ...}` after `=>`

Comment: @Jeff, Put this as answer. Its working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `{form, collider}` is not correct syntax.
If it should be an object as key/value pair it'd be `{form: collider}`.

Comment: Thanks @jeff. Can you please look this question and guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549914/checkbox-focus-is-not-showing-in-ie-and-firefox-while-pressing-tab-keys?noredirect=1#comment86109437_49549914